# Как изменить вид вкладок в FireFOX

Tags: firefox

Я хочу изменить вид вкладок современной версии FireFOX

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот на такие, как в версии до 29:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. сделать прямоугольными, без закругления

Comment: уже согласен с плагинами?))

Comment: ну да, ну да...

Comment: Ну ты явно не там вопрос задал... Не имеет отношения к программированию...

Comment: а тут разве никто не может подсказать?

Comment: Вопрос на данный вопрос можно найти погуглить... Ты предлагаешь за тебя гуглить?

Comment: я гуглил, но не нашел

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что оффтопик.

Comment: плагин Classic Theme Restorer

Comment: @Hellraiser хотите прямоугольными и без закругления - просто обновитесь до Firefox 57 версии, там они прямоугольные :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте

Пользуюсь этим плагином для того, чтобы меню было в старом стиле и только сейчас узнал, что он еще и вкладки делает "квадратными".

[ClassicTheme Restorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/)